# MultiValueMap in java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm studying with Hashmap with Multiple parameters(1 key, 2 values)
and i was able to find apache multiValueMap for my issue.

Here is my codes for multiValueMap.

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap;

public class multiValueMap {

public static void main(String args[]) {
   String a, b, c;
   MultiMap mMap = new MultiValueMap();

   mMap.put("a", "Hello there, It's a wonderful day");
   mMap.put("a", "nice to meet you");

   Set<String> keys = mMap.keySet();

   for (String key : keys) {
      System.out.println("Key = " + key);
      System.out.println("Values = " + mMap.get(key));
      a = String.valueOf(mMap.get(key));

      System.out.println("A : " + a);
    }
 }
}
// The result as below
 Key = a 
 Value = [Hello there, It's a wonderful day, nice to meet you]
 A : [Hello there, It's a wonderful day, nice to meet you]
```

Here is my question 
**how can I store first value for string b, and second for c?**
if I substring the MultiMap values depends on "," then it would stores Hello there only.
please give me helpful your advices.

Comment: Don't want to be that guy, but: why wouldn't you just store a List in a Map?

Comment: @PieterDeBie That's what the commons `MultiValueMap` does under the hood

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try following :

```
String a, b, c;

MultiMap mMap = new MultiValueMap();
mMap.put("a", "Hello there, It's a wonderful day");
mMap.put("a", "nice to meet you");

Set<String> keys = mMap.keySet();

for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
    System.out.println("Values = " + mMap.get(key));
    List<String> list = (List<String>) mMap.get(key);

    b = list.get(0);
    c = list.get(1);
    System.out.println("B : " + b);
    System.out.println("C : " + c);
}
```

Comment: Seems like it needs more details. actually, I want to store numerous data(more than 1000) from DB and it covers 3 parameters(data no(int), channel id(int), description(String)). but If I store them to Hashmap(Key, Value) It's not enough for 3 paramets hence, I decided to use MultiValueMap. 2 answers above does not fully solve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do a split. This is the documentation of MultiMap that is found:

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
 mhm.put(key, "A");
 mhm.put(key, "B");
 mhm.put(key, "C");
 Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

Now when you do a `get()` call on a multimap, it gives you a collection. The first item will be your b and the second one will be your c.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a key and object to store multiple values in Multimap.
Something like this,
MultiValueMap mv = new LinkedMultiValueMap<~>();

Answer (score 0):

@user3810857 you have to make a wrapper with 3 fields(data no(int), channel id(int), description(String)) that you retrieve from DB, then you can make normal or multivalue map according to your requirement with wrapper as your value.